# Who first discussed the Lorentz force with respect to special relativity?

Tags: physics, relativity-theory

The fact that a [Lorentz force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_force) in a reference frame 1 can become a [Coulomb force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coulomb's_law) in another reference frame 2 has always astonished me, especially because the velocities involved are really small.

I wonder: who was the first to discuss this peculiar interpretation (or effect) of Lorentz transformations of the EM-field?

In [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relativistic_electromagnetism) a letter from Einstein is mentioned in which he writes:

> What led me more or less directly to the special theory of relativity was the conviction that the electromotive force acting on a body in motion in a magnetic field was nothing else but an electric field.

However, this letter dates from 1953. I wonder whether Einstein really discussed this in his earlier articles? Did he not mainly discuss the effects in space-time-coordinates of an invariant and finite speed of light? Further I noted that a publication by E. Purcell from 1965 is often referenced.

Are there also publications known from the beginning of the 20th century? So, not publications that deal with Lorentz-transformations of the EM-field in general, but that specifically discuss changes in charge distiributions due to length contraction etc.

Comment: I believe the answer to your question is in Einstein's 1905 famous paper Zur Elektrodynamik bewegter Körper (On the Electrodynamics of Moving Bodies) in the second section *Electrodynamical Part*. Internet is full of translations and the original, if you know german. Here's a link: :fourmilab.ch/etexts/einstein/specrel/www/#tex2html10

Comment: @Javier: I am looking for the first publication that discusses the intricacies of the space-time interpretation of the Lorentz-transformation of EM-forces. In this original article A.E. deduces and uses the transformation, but he doesn't discuss their space-time intricacies.

Comment: I see. Maybe you should check the articles references. Let's see what other users have to say about it :)

Comment: I just realized Einstein's paper doesn't have any references. (!!!)

Comment: @Javier Yeah, just try to get away with that today. =D

Comment: @DavidH I know, I really don't know how I feel about this given that special relativity was hardly Einstein's own merit.